# What is parity useful for in physics?

Tags: symmetry, conventions, parity

What do we gain by defining the parity of different objects in physics? I can learn that $L$ (angular momentum) has the opposite parity as $p$ (linear momentum) or $B$ (magnetic field) hass opposite parity as $E$ (electric field) but I don't see how this information is useful to me. It just feels like stamp collecting.

I know that I can sometimes use parity one one object to deduce the parity of another object, but that's also not interesting because it's just parity informing parity. Feels circular.

What makes parity a useful concept?

Note I'm decently well-versed in things like differential geometry and the effect of coordinate (passive or active) transformations on components or bases of vectors/tensors.
However, I'm pretty poorly versed in particle physics, the standard model, and the phenomenology thereof. So if you're answer relies heavily on those latter things I would appreciate extended explanations with some background supporting detail, or at least links with clear explanations for background/support.

Finally a realistic disclaimer: I'm not looking for hand waving. I'm looking for rigorous definitions and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

The parities of two atomic states (or nuclear states) factor into the [selection rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule) for transitions between them mediated by electromagnetism, which in turn influences decay rates.

Consider a transition from $J^\pi=1^-\to0^+$, perhaps where a single electron goes from a $p$-wave orbital to an $s$-wave orbital.  In order to conserve both angular momentum and parity, the emitted EM field may contain multipole moments of electric dipole E1, magnetic quadrupole M2, electric octupole E3, and so on. (The dipole part of the transition dominates over the higher-$L$ components.)

Now consider a transition $1^+\to0^+$, perhaps an $s$-wave electron undergoing a spin flip.
The allowed multipole components of the emitted field are now M1, E2, M3, and so on.  The magnetic-dipole coupling is weaker than the electric dipole coupling, so an M1 transition will be slower than an E1 transition with the same energy.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I do have to admit that it was this exact topic (EM vector multipole emission of light from atoms) that helped spur this question on for me.

I'm a bit confused about how to derive parity for these modes. Maybe you could comment on or answer my specific question about that here to help me out me: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/703184/parity-of-the-vector-spherical-harmonics

Comment: But in the meantime, would it be correct to say both that the electric and magnetic fields (in general) have certain symmetries under parity (i.e. electric has -1 parity and magnetic has +1 parity) but also that the entire modes the electromagnetic field can ALSO have some symmetry under parity? For example E1, M2, E3 are odd under parity while M1, E2, M3 are even under parity? I think I get confused about the parity of the generic physical field compared to the parity of a specific solution for the EM field.